# Set timeout on org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-commons

I have some code that copies using httpCore util copyURLtoFile() but I can't seem to find anything about timeouts in the documentation like I was able to with httpClient.   The file it's pulling shouldn't pull out, but depending on that is.... interesting.

```
    URL pjmUrl = new URL("myFile");
    File projLoad = new File("projLoad.txt");
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(pjmUrl, projLoad);
```

If the third line should timeout, the program has no way to throw an error based on runtime or to check for threadInterrupted()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be looking at old javadocs.  In the current release (2.4) here is an overload of the `copyURLToFile` method that has two timeout parameters:

```
  public static void copyURLToFile(URL source,
                             File destination,
                             int connectionTimeout,
                             int readTimeout)
                      throws IOException
```

As the javadoc explains, the time unit is milliseconds.

Reference:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Answer (score 2):

Not true, the overloaded method

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL source,
                        File destination,
                        int connectionTimeout,
                        int readTimeout)
```

**does not exist in the latest 2.4. version**, although the method is listed in Javadoc:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyURLToFile(java.net.URL,%20java.io.File,%20int,%20int)

I'm positively sure that I'm using the 2.4 version of Apache commons-io.

P.S.: I also downloaded source (http://www.carfab.com/apachesoftware//commons/io/source/commons-io-2.4-src.zip) to make sure that the above method really doesn't exist (anymore?) and inside `FileUtils.java` there really isn't such method.

Comment: I find it, using commons-io 2.4 I can see the function on line 1483 of FileUtils.java. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java?av=f#1484

Comment: Downloading copies of the Apache source code from "random" 3rd parties is dodgy.  You have no idea if it is the real code.  Download the source bundle from the official Apache site, or checkout the source code from their repos.

Comment: And looking back at the place that you downloaded the source from, it appears that "www.carfab.com" might have been a dodgy "organization".

Answer (score 0):

Check your maven dependencies, there might be another older version of common-io jar in your classpath. I had the same issue.